# R: Selecting a transformation approach/pipeline using a recommended grid

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

When using the R package “sf” to reproject a shapefile from WGS 84 to EPSG:7991 (NAD 27 MTM 10) is there a way to specify a particular transformation and grid? I know that the new-ish function sf_proj_pipelines will allow me to explore available options, which I can then specify.  But if the one I need, using the particular grid I need, is not available, is there some other option?

For what it’s worth, when testing out the transformations I needed in QGIS via GUI, QGIS actually prompts me to download and install the grid I need. If I have the grid stored locally, can I refer to it from R?

Comment: When you say "grid" do you mean like a UTM projection? You can transform `sf` objects into a new projection using `st_transform(my_data, 7991)` (which is EPSG:7991 like your question). Does this help?